# Minimalist Image Slider containing bare minimum HTML & CSS using background-image transition

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background, background-image

While trying to set the background with as minimal code as possible HTML code (and put as much as possible into CSS) i'm stuck in this **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7vb0rgt/)** demo.

**MAIN QUESTION**
Why are the third and fourth slide not the same background *size* and *center* origin as the first and second slide? Removing the `-image` part and using just the shorthand `background` apparently breaks the background position and centering, despite these rules being explicitely set in the CSS. What have I overlooked?

**BONUS QUESTION**
The transision has two effects: first a horizontal sliding effect followed by a zoom-in at the end. Is it possible to make both effects to work parallel in stead of one after another? In other words to start the zoom while the slide is horizontally sliding, for a more dynamic smooth transition?

.

`style="background-image: url(https://...`
Gives the desired zoom/centering result, with background image fitting/centering nicely:
[image]

.

`style="background: url(https://...`
Gives an undesired result, with background image not fitting/centering correctly:
[image]

Comment: What are the <container> and <slide> tags? These tags are not in the list of valid tags - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov  its just for this example, and it wont make any difference for the result here.

Comment: Even for a simple example, you need to use valid tags. First, some tags have styles that can affect your code. Secondly, invalid tags in your question can confuse newbies here.

Comment: I see what you mean. Agree with that. Especially the newbies part (which includes myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS variables are made for this purpose and you can adjust the background-size to have the need transition effect:

```css
container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 612px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 306px;
}

slide {
  flex: 1;
  background-image: var(--i);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  padding: 2px 0 0 2px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all .67s ease;
}

container slide:hover {
  flex: 15;
  background-size: auto 120%;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <slide style="--i: url(https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/729829/screenshots/4185141/galshir-cactus-coffee.png)">1</slide>
  <slide style="--i: url(https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/729829/screenshots/6146136/galshir-tea-biscuit_2x.png)">2</slide>
  <slide style="--i: url(https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/729829/screenshots/4185141/galshir-cactus-coffee.png)">3</slide>
  <slide style="--i: url(https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/729829/screenshots/6146136/galshir-tea-biscuit_2x.png)">4</slide>
</container>
```

Comment: +1 Wow nice! thanks for your input! That solves my question! I Never thought it was possible to introduce variables in CSS in such a neat way! I assume `i` could be anythyng like `bg` or `A`  etc?!

Comment: @Sam yes of course, I used `i` because it was the smallest letter I could find :p

Comment: @Sam by the way, I have also answered your bonus question, why did you remove it?

Comment: I see it now mate! Im putting the bonus question back in one second! I followed s.kuznetsov's advise to make a new question for that, but now that I see you have solved it its a 5/5 stars!!! <3

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for this behavior in your code is that you specified rule `background` in the styles attribute, inside the tags.:

```
<slide style="background: url()">3</slide>
```

The styles in the attribute take precedence over the styles in the css!

When using the shorthand `background`, all of the following rules are overwritten:

```
slide {
    ...
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    ...
}
```

Because `background` already contains **default** values that differ from the values I indicated above.

The default rewriting values, the `background`, as well as the `background` specified in the attributes of the **style**, is the source of the problem in your code.

My advice:

- don't declare styles in attributes yourself unnecessarily;
- use `background-image`;
- always use **valid tags** (even for SO examples):
- you can use `!important` to override `background` rules:

Like that:

```
slide {
    ...
    background-position: center !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-origin: content-box !important;
    background-clip: border-box !important;
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks @s.kuznetsov for your clear answer. I think I understand what you mean. The shorthand overrides all specified rules so the shorthand cannot be used here. Okay. But is there no other shorter or cleaner way to keep all my background CSS rules in place and only set/override the background-image src in HTML? And how about the bonus question? Should I ask that in a separate question perhaps?

Comment: @Sam, Yes, you can override the rules with css using `!important` :) I update my answer and wrote this in my answer, at the very bottom, in the **My advice**. The bonus question is best asked as a separate question. Because you get a mixed question-answer, and it will not be very convenient for those people who will ever read your question with a similar problem like this one.

Comment: "@Sam, As for the bonus question ... do you want to make your animations synchronous?

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments! I will ask that transition effect in a new quetsion and link to it in a few minutes :)